# Java vs. C variant for desktop and tablet development

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, c

I am going to write a desktop application, but I am conflicted concerning which language to use. It (the desktop application) will need to have a good GUI, and to be extendable (hopefully good with modules of some sort). It must be completely cross-platform, including executable in various tablet environments. I put this as a requirement while realizing that some modification will no doubt be necessary. The language should also have some form of networking tools available.

I have read http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/c2java.html and understand the differences between Java and C very well. I am looking not necessarily at C, but more at a C variant.

If it is a complete toss-up, I will use Java as I know Java much better. However, I do not want to use a language that will be inferior for the task I wish to accomplish. Thank you for all suggestions and explanations.

NOTE: If this is not the correct stack for this question, I apologize. It seemed appropriate according to the rules.

Comment: By 'various tablet environments', which tablet OSes are you including? Android, iOS, and Windows RT are the three big ones (others do exist as well).

Comment: Re-read the site rules please. This question will just invite debate, argument and polling.

Comment: Could you perhaps suggest a site where this would be better suited in that case? My intention is not to invite arguments, but to obtain a well-constructed, reasonable response.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to develop a GUI application and wish to deploy it in multi-environment system, Building software in C is a `tough path` to take!! If you are proficient in java and willing to learn some new things on the way, I would suggest to use software like `PhoneGap` (phonegap.com)

if u wish to develop software for multiple tablet environment then `PhoneGap` (phonegap.com) will definitely help you.

Comment: I was just about to suggest exactly the same thing.  *FORGET* about "Java vs C" (or, for that matter, Objective-C or C#) and focus on HTML5, CSS, Javascript ... and a nice, cross-platform mobile framework like Phonegap.  IMHO...

Comment: I want the application to be portable to tablets, but it will be a desktop application first.

Comment: OH.. in that case take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455353/cross-platform-desktop-application), might help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are ton of cross platform apps written in a lot of languages, if you end up building a successful product then you have the resources to get it ported to any platform. Using Java vs. C is not going to make your app perfect for the targeted tablet / OS. TO build a good app it is going to be spending a lot of time getting feedback from uses and figuring out ways to make the product better.

I don't know what your app does, but you get more options based on building with the right architecture approach. For example if the app is talking to a server, then focus on defining a good set of Request / Response formatted as JSON then if you change your back end technology then the front end does not have to change. If there is no back end server focus on the architecture within the app write clean testable, code, ... etc.

So I suggest you go with the language that you feel you can be productive in, write clean code, and as you develop a better understanding of your product then you can always port / rewrite ... etc.